# Word array with whitespace

Tags: ruby, arrays

I came to love **word arrays**, but today I face a challenge:

```
 > a = %w[ faq contact 'about us' legal 'bug reports' ]
 => ["faq", "contact", "'about", "us'", "legal", "'bug", "reports'"] 
 > a = %w[ faq contact "about us" legal 'bug reports' ]
 => ["faq", "contact", "\"about", "us\"", "legal", "'bug", "reports'"]
```

How can I have **whitespace** an element?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can escape space characters

```
a = %w[ faq contact about\ us legal bug\ reports ]
a # => ["faq", "contact", "about us", "legal", "bug reports"]
```

But I'd still consider using "full" array literals. They are less confusing in this case.

Comment: Absolutely. Using a whitespace separated list declarator with non-whitespace separated data is asking for trouble.